# Change global variable in usage every time the user logins in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, session, request

One of the functionalities that the website I'm building requires is the ability to change a value from the login view, and that value will show in every other module/view on the entire site. For this, I made a select dropdown to choose said variable, and supposedly that variable must be shown everywhere the user goes.

[image]

To make a global variable in Laravel, I need to create a file in the folder /config and call the file with the variable in the controller I need. I already call an example variable to show it at the beginning of the website.

**config_ciclos.php**

```
<?php
 return [
'variables' => [
    'ciclo1' => '20-21',
    'ciclo2' => '21-22',
    'ciclo3' => '22-23'
 ],
];
```

**HomeController**

```
public function index()
{
    $ciclo = config('config_ciclo.variables.ciclo1');
    $auth = Auth::id();
    if ($auth != null) {
        return view('home', compact('ciclo'));
    } else {
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

The only thing that eludes me is how can I make a variable that I can pass every time a user logs in that dictates what global variable is in use?

I wondered if I could create a variable inside the request on login similar to a user session. Then, I could call every controller to select the global variable I'm using, which expires after the session's time limit. However, I don't know how to do that. The only thing I'm sure of is that maybe I could use the file *AuthenticatesUsers.php* because all the methods of auth and login are there.

Comment: there are multiple ways, either you can define your session variable in base controller constructor so you don't have to manually parse on individual controller. or you can setup variable in your middleware and access it on group of middleware routes.

Comment: Hey did my answer work for you? If so do not forget to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Laravel Auth Controller, you can put data to your session or you can use event/listener approach.

LoginController.php

```
// Store a piece of data in the session...
session(['config_ciclo' => config('config_ciclo.variables.ciclo1')]);
```

and get value in your view like:

```
$value = session('config_ciclo);
```